# Modify behaviour of viewDidAppear in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, categories

I have application (UICatalog from Apple samples). I am using it with a framework called Lookback which is intended for screen recording.

I have interface defined as follows:

```
@interface AAPLSteppperViewController : UITableViewController
```

So it is in a straight way a subclass of UITableViewController. And it has implemented a methods as follows:

```
+ (NSString*)lookbackIdentifier {
    return @"Profile Editor";
}
```

I wanted to investigate how lookbackIdentifier is being called and see something like that:

[image: Call stack]

The question is: how to introduce such behavior as UITableViewController is a system class and I am not able to see the source of calls numbered 1 and 2 at the stack?

As I investigated framework docs, they recommend to implement always like that

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    ...
}
```

As for me it looks like a change inside UIViewController - but how to achieve something like that?

I guess that it will include some playing with UIViewController but - how? I can't imagine how to override a single method of it without subclasssing.

I have only access to my AAPLSteppperViewController.

I would be grateful if somebody could give me a push in the right direction

Comment: I don't think I really understand your question but you can override a single method without subclassing using method swizzling

Comment: Sounds like a plan. I would like to achieve e.g. UIViewController in viewDidAppear calling something additional.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @dan pointed - swizzling is the right answer. I tried with instructions there: http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/ and it gave me desired behaviour.

Thanks for help :)